# tensorflow upgrade failed on google datalab

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

Datalab currently seems to be running 0.6.0. I wanted to update to version 0.8.0

I did:

```
 !pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64
```

I got:

```
 SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)

 Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you get that error if you access https://storage.googleapis.com/ using your browser as well? If so then there might be some weirdness going on between you and your ISP. This error does not seem to be related to the software but seems to be a problem with pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to update packages which are installed in Datalab by default. This is to ensure that you do not break a working Datalab environment.

Please try one of the following solutions:

- If you deployed Datalab using https://datalab.cloud.google.com/ , visit the [Datalab GitHub Issues](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues) page and submit an issue to have a new version of datalab published. In the Datalab source code on github, tensorflow is at version 0.8.0)
- If you have installed Datalab locally, or on GCE, then simply rebuild the Datalab image to get tensorflow 0.8.0 . See the [Datalab Getting Started Wiki page](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/wiki/Getting-Started) for more information.

If you want to temporarily install a newer version into your existing environment for testing purposes (although this isn't recommended) , then you could try installing tensorflow with the no dependencies option (--no-deps) in order to reduce the chance of breaking the working datalab environment.

```
%%bash
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl && pip install --ignore-installed --no-deps tensorflow-0.8.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

After running the above command, I can see tensorflow is at version 0.8.0.

```
>> import tensorflow
>> tensorflow.__version__
'0.8.0'

>>!pip show tensorflow
---
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: tensorflow
Version: 0.8.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: http://tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
Installer: pip
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: six, protobuf, wheel, numpy
```

Please keep an eye out for any anomalies now that you have updated a package used by datalab. For example, certain sample notebooks may not work. Also, please note that this setup may not be supported. For example, you may encounter an issue which is directly related to updating a package used by datalab. In that case, the solution may be to revert the updated package and see if that resolves your issue.