# tf.nn.dynamic_rnn() returning error when used in Google Cloud Datalab

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-datalab

I'm trying to run an RNN on Google Cloud Datalab. The same network runs correctly on my computer, but when I run it on Datalab, I get the following error:

TypeError: dynamic_rnn() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)

The use of dynamic_rnn() is as follows:

rnn_outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cells, inputs, initial_state = initial_state_placeholder)

Is this a tensorflow version problem. On my computer I'm using tensorflow-0.9.0, from the latest GPU pip install for Ubuntu. Is Cloud Datalab perhaps using a different version, in which the use of dynamic_rnn() has changed slightly?

UPDATE: Have checked version of tensorflow imported into Datalab - it's 0.7.1. I assume there's no way of importing a newer version if this is what's causing the problem?

I'm following the directions for use here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard8/tf.nn.dynamic_rnn.md

Many thanks.

Comment: Please check the version of tensorflow by running the following code in a cell within the Datalab notebook:
`import tensorflow as tf` followed by  `tf.__version__`

Comment: Checked the version - it's 0.7.1. Does that release feature a version of dynamic_rnn perhaps? I assume there's no way of importing a more recent version into datalab is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dynamic_rnn` does not appear to be listed in the [api docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/nn.html) of tensorflow 0.7.

As a next step, you could try one of the following options:

- Deploy a newer version of Datalab. This is the recommended option. The latest version uses tensorflow 0.9.0.
- Upgrade tensorflow to version 0.9.0 by running the command below in a Datalab notebook. See my explanation in the following [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464668/tensorflow-upgrade-failed-on-google-datalab/37604626#37604626) explaining why this is not recommended (but it may work).

Note for tensorflow version 0.9.0 use:

```
%%bash
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-datalab/deploy/tf/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl && pip install --ignore-installed --no-deps tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl && rm tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```